# Best way to pass down data in a series of functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, functional-programming

I am working on a Node.js web scraper application with some code like so below and trying to orient my code functionally. See below:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const scrapeUri = uri => fetch(uri); // how should i pass the uri from here
const fetchURIs = URIs => Promise.all(URIs.map(scrapeUri));
const getBodies = pages => Promise.all(pages.map(page => page.text()));
const toSource = source => cheerio.load(source);
const shouldScrape = ($) => {
  const shouldIndex = $('meta[name="robots"]').attr('content');
  if (['noindex', 'nofollow'].indexOf(shouldIndex) !== -1) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
};

const objectifyContent = ($) => { // to be accessed here
  return {
    meta: {
      index_timestamp: new Date(),
      title: $('title').html(),
      // TODO: this will totally fail in some instances, need to pass uri from initial instance
      uri: $('link[rel="canonical"]').attr('href'),
      description: $('meta[name="description"]').attr('content'),
    },
  };
};
```

In `objectifyContent`, what would be a pure way of accessing the uri from the initial `scrapeUri` instead of trying to get the page's url by accessing the canonical? I know of some ways I could set a variable and have it inherit down the scope, but I was wondering if there is a cleaner, more functional way of performing in this in the context of Node.js.

The caller would resemble:
`fetchUris(myUris).then(values => getBodies(values).then(sources => res.send(sources.map(toSource).filter(shouldScrape).map(objectifyContent));)`

Comment: Why not simply add it to the signature of `objectifyContent`?  Is that signature dictated by some framework?  If not, can't you just make it either `($, uri) => { ...}` or `($) => (uri) => {... }`?  (Or the reverse order, depending on your taste and which is most likely to change.)

Comment: I guess the question is, these functions are used in a series where `objectifyContent` is at the end of a series of `map`s and `filter`s. How do I store each array's uri for use later in the series?

Comment: You'd have to show us that actual code where you're using `.map()` and `.filter()` for us to offer the best answer in that context.  Perhaps what you want to be accumulating is an array of objects with several properties rather than just filtering a single value.  They you can store multiple pieces of information for each unit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify this `scrapeUri` to pass the URI through the promise, and modify your handlers accordingly

```
const scrapeUri = uri => fetch(uri).then(
  webpage => [uri, webpage]
)
```

Comment: This is essentially the idea I went with, except that I used `Promise.props` and used objects rather than arrays.